# Getting wrong integer when trying to read through an array via linked list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, linked-list

I've been trying to create a program that will read through a fixed array via linked list. Whenever I run my code, the program gives me a clearly inaccurate number and will not iterate through the array. Any advice on what i'm doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct number
{
int array[10];
struct number *next;
};

int main()
{

    struct number array[10] = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};

    struct number *head = 0;
    struct number *tail = 90;

    array[0].next = &array[1];
    array[1].next = &array[2];
    array[2].next = &array[3];
    array[3].next = &array[4];
    array[4].next = &array[5];
    array[5].next = &array[6];
    array[6].next = &array[7];
    array[7].next = &array[8];
    array[8].next = &array[9];
    array[9].next = NULL;

    printf("%i", array[10].array[2]);

    struct number *current = head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        printf("Node %i contains the element and is stored in address %p\n", current->array[0], current);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: `struct number array[10] = ...` --> this will create array of 10 elements of type `struct number` instead of initializing `int array[10];` member of `struct number`. Try compiling your program with turn on all warnings `-Wall`.

Comment: `struct number *tail = 90;` --> assigning an `int` value to `struct number *` pointer. Isnt compiler throwing warning for this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working is because of the initializers for `struct number`. More information on using C initializers can be found [on the GCC website.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)

**Struct Initializer:** `struct number array[10] = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};`

This is an ambiguous way of initializing a struct that evaluates to

```
struct number array[10];
array[0].array = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90};
```

**Head pointer:**

```
struct number *head = 0;
...
struct number *current = head;
while(current != NULL)
```

The first line, `struct number *head = 0;`, is equivalent to `struct number *head = NULL;` As is, your while loop will never be executed. You could use either `head = array;` or `head = &array[0];` here.

**Tail pointer:**  `struct number *tail = 90;`

This gives the following warning in VS2015 -

```
Warning C4047 'initializing': 'number *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
```

You could use `tail = &array[9];` here.

**Print Error:** `printf("%i", array[10].array[2]);`

This is accessing an element outside the bounds of `array`. C generally uses 0-based indices, so for your definition `struct number array[10]`, the maximum element is `array[9]`.